# Macro button to change cell values

Tags: vba, excel

I found this link on Stack Overflow, and it did help a lot: [Change Cell Values with Macro](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34454544/excel-macro-button-to-change-change-cell-values).  I used the answer provided by @Jeeped.

This changes cell values from 1 to 7 by macro button presses. When it reaches 7 it starts from 1 again.

But, I would like to use TWO buttons, one counting down, the other up,
and, when reaching 1 the downcounting button presses shouldn't affect the
digits any more, to change you would have to press UP button to count up from
the number 1.

How should I do this?

Comment: can you show us how far you've gotten, i.e. where exactly you are struggling?

Comment: If there is just one cell requiring it, why not use a SpinButton? A dynamic one can be done by Worksheet_Change event and change the Spinner's LinkedCell, move next to the activecell etc.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you want to mimic the behaviour of the other question in that the buttons move the target value through a list of values found in a range. This is obviously different to simply incrementing or decrementing a value.

Caveat: as per the other question, this requires that the values in the list are unique.

The following is similar to the code from the other question. It moves down the table. Difference: it stops at the last value (does not go back to the start).

```
Sub ButtonDown_Click()
    Dim targetCell As Range
    Set targetCell = Range("A1")
    Dim tableRange As Range
    Set tableRange = Range("B1:B10")
    If IsError(Application.Match(targetCell.Value, tableRange, 0)) Then
        'if value in the target cell is not in the table then reset to the first value in table
        targetCell.Value = tableRange.Cells(1).Value
    ElseIf Application.Match(targetCell.Value, tableRange, 0) < tableRange.Cells.Count Then
        'if value in the target cell is NOT the last value in the table then move to the next value in the table
        targetCell.Value = tableRange.Cells(1).Offset(Application.Match(targetCell.Value, tableRange, 0), 0).Value
    End If
End Sub
```

The following is code for another button which moves up through the table. It stops when it gets to the first value.

```
Sub ButtonUp_Click()
    Dim targetCell As Range
    Set targetCell = Range("A1")
    Dim tableRange As Range
    Set tableRange = Range("B1:B10")
    If IsError(Application.Match(targetCell.Value, tableRange, 0)) Then
        'if value in the target cell is not in the table then reset to the first value in table
        targetCell.Value = tableRange.Cells(1).Value
    ElseIf Application.Match(targetCell.Value, tableRange, 0) > 1 Then
        'if value in the target cell is NOT the first value in the table then move to the previous value in the table
        targetCell.Value = tableRange.Cells(1).Offset(Application.Match(targetCell.Value, tableRange, 0) - 2, 0).Value
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Ok, this seems to be what I'm looking for. What would we do without the different forums, you just don't need to know everything, hopefully I can help someone else in another way, and it comes around to You some day