# Excel button that shows the elements of the previous row

Tags: excel, vba

I used the code from https://stackoverflow.com/a/34454648/11447549
I got it to use dynamic column length and take values from a cell in another sheet. This code currently gives me the element of the next row(i.e., A1 -> click -> A2) and then if the last element, it returns to the first one.
Know I need this to go backward. It needs to go from bottom to up and if it hits the first one, go to the last one. I tried my reversing the parameters of `Range`but got an error.
Any ideas or hints will be very useful.

```
Sub Button8_Click()
    Set wsh = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    Column = wsh.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    If IsError(Application.Match(Range("B2").Value, wsh.Range(wsh.Cells(2, 1), wsh.Cells(Column, 1)), 0)) Then
        Range("B2").Value = wsh.Cells(2, 1).Value
    ElseIf Application.Match(Range("B2").Value, wsh.Range(wsh.Cells(2, 1), wsh.Cells(Column, 1)), 0) = wsh.Range(wsh.Cells(2, 1), wsh.Cells(Column, 1)).Cells.Count Then
        Range("B2").Value = wsh.Cells(2, 1).Value
    Else
        Range("B2").Value = wsh.Cells(2, 1).Offset(Application.Match(Range("B2").Value, wsh.Range(wsh.Cells(2, 1), wsh.Cells(Column, 1)), 0), 0).Value
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Is it possible to have duplicate entries in column A?  If so, that algorithm (even altered to go bottom up) will fail.

Comment: @RonRosenfeld No, I'm using this as a word list to help me memorize them. There are no duplicate entries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are absolutely certain there are no duplicates, you can use the `Range.Find` method, which is a built-in VBA function.

```
Option Explicit
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim rDest As Range, rCol As Range, C As Range
    Dim wsSrc As Worksheet
    Dim myRow As Long, LR As Long

Set wsSrc = Worksheets("sheet2") 'or whatever

With wsSrc
    Set rCol = .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp))
End With

Set rDest = Cells(2, 2)

With rCol
    Set C = .Find(what:=rDest, after:=rCol(1, 1), LookIn:=xlValues, _
                lookat:=xlWhole, searchorder:=xlByRows, searchdirection:=xlPrevious)
    If Not C Is Nothing Then
      If C.Row = 1 Then Set C = rCol(rCol.Rows.Count + 1, 1)
        rDest = C.Offset(-1, 0)
    Else
        rDest = rCol(rCol.Rows.Count, 1)
    End If
End With
End Sub
```

Comment: How do I use it when the destination, B2, is in sheet 2 and the source, column A, is in sheet 1? It's my first day with VBA and the only method I know to access data from another sheet is using ```ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("sheet")```but I can't find anything like this in here.

Comment: Thank you! One last thing. I tried to ignore the first row of the column because of the headers. So I tried changing ```.Cells(1,1)``` and ```after:=rCol(1,1)```but achieved nothing. Same for the columns if I change the column index for ```.Cells(.Row.Count, 1).End(xlUp)``` the column changes. Then what is the column index for ```.Cells(1,1)```used for??

Comment: @MosesKim won't be at computer for a day or two but try changing `if c.row=1` to `if c.row=2`

Answer (score 0):

I find your code cumbersome (or perhaps not complicated enough :-)). Here is another version. It works on double-click on A1. It needs to be installed in the code sheet of the worksheet on which you want the action.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)

    Const Rstart As Long = 2                ' set as required

    Dim Rng As Range
    Dim Rcount As Long
    Dim R As Variant

    With Target
        If .Address = Range("A1").Address Then
            ' from Rstart to last row in column B
            Set Rng = Range(Cells(Rstart, "B"), Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp))
            Rcount = Rng.Cells.Count

            On Error Resume Next
            R = Application.Match(.Value, Rng, 0)
            If Err Then
                R = Rcount
            Else
                R = R + 1
                If R > Rcount Then R = 1
            End If

            .Value = Rng.Cells(R).Value

            .Offset(1).Select
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

Once you understand the code it is both easier to read and to modify. For example, to change the cell A1, all you need to do is to change the reference to A1 in this line of code. *If .Address = Range("A1").Address*.

Your list of choices need not start in row 1. *Const Rstart* now has a value of 2, meaning your list starts in row 2, allowing for a column caption, but you can change it to 1, if you prefer, or 3.

The line of code *Set Rng = Range(Cells(Rstart, "B"), Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp))* sets the range of your list to column B. Change the two "B"s to move it to another column. It finds the end dynamically. The beginning is taken from the setting of *Rstart*.

Finally, there is no button. But if you prefer a button to double-click it will be easy to adapt the code to the use of one.

What would be the good of "finally" if there weren't one more word to say. This code can easily be adapted to have different triggers referring to different lists on the same sheet. For example, you could move the list now in column B to be below A1. In column B you could have another list that responds to a double-click in B1 etc.